# show multiple markers from mysql table on the map

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I wrote php code to generate xml from database table. this xml file contains the lat,lng of the markers. then I wrote this code to show the markers on the map:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
<?php
require("phpsqlsearch_genxml.php");
?>
var customIcons = {
  restaurant: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
  },
   bar: {
     icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
   }
   };

  function load() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.6557, 46.7351),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
     });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("test.xml", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      //var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

  //]]>

 </script>

 </head>

 <body onload="load()">
 <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

but I got the following wrong msg:

```
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: http://localhost/onlinetaxi/1.php
Line Number 8, Column 5:    var customIcons = {
----^
```

knewing that the file phpsqlsearch_genxml.php generates the xml file and save it as "test.xml" in the same directory.
can anybody tell me why and how to repair it???
and if I deleted the lines:

the web pag will show the map, but without the markers. why?????

Comment: Please do not post live-code here in questions. Instead reduce the code to the bare minimum to reproduce the error. Make it self contained, that is with all code and data (keep in mind to minimize it to the *bare* minimum) that can be run right away. This works best by creating a new example from scratch (that even often already helps you spotting the more obvious mistakes you made with the original code).